# find comand with -exec ls produces a different output

Tags: find, ls

I am trying to determine which files will be touched based on their modified date. My directory is a top a list of perhaps several levels of subdirectories.

From a terminal window I run this command:

```
find Program.8.koeb/ -mtime -10
```

Which correctly produces a list of files modified within the past 10 days.
However if I want to query this list to make sure that the files I want to touch using the `find` command, I would run this command:

```
find Program.8.koebe/ -mtime -10 -exec ls -gotrhR {} \;
```

Which produces a long list of all the files within directories of my current working directory, including subdirectories, along with the named directory `find` is assigned to look. So, `-exec ls -gotrhR {} \;` seems to be producing the same output as:

```
find . -mtime -10 -exec ls -gotrhR {} \;
```

Which is not my intention.

Comment: Why would you run `ls -R`, when `find` is already recursive? Why would you run `ls` manually at all, when `find` has an `-ls` command?

Comment: As far as I know, the -ls in find does not take switch arguments, thus the output is rather cluttered with unreadable file size numbers - there is also no total size values given for each listed directory. I use the -go switch in ls to remove my user name from all the listed files owner and groups, since this is of no use to someone who will read a print out of the results.

Comment: the size reported by ls is useless as a size of the directory and its contents. Are you looking for `du`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add '-type f' cause -exec ls -l {} will include those are directories and list them, too.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a directory to `ls`, it lists the files in that directory, not the directory itself. With the `-R` flag, `ls` lists files in subdirectories recursively. To make `ls` list directories rather than their contents, pass the `-d` option.

The `-t` and `-r` flag are useless since they only affect sorting and you're listing one file at a time.

```
find Program.8.koebe/ -mtime -10 -exec ls -gohd {} \;
```

With GNU find, you can use `-printf` instead of invoking an external command. The output format will be similar but not exactly identical.

```
find Program.8.koebe/ -mtime -10 -printf '%M %n %s %M %c %p\n'
```

Comment: thanks for the answers Gilles - the -t and the -r are actually quite helpful for me in the reports that I create, though. I knew of the -printf switch but never used it so much. I haven't tried to tweak the -printf parameters to produce a clean read out yet.

Comment: @Gustav `ls -rt` doesn't do anything when you pass one file at a time. `find … -exec ls -trd {} +` would call `ls` in batches, so it will sort, but only *per batch*: if there are too many files, `ls` will be called multiple times and so the output won't be sorted. To get sorted output, your best bet is to use a parseable date format (ideally YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and pipe through `sort`. Or use zsh globbing flags (which requires installing the `zsh` package).